# Reset default value of input in jquery

Tags: jquery, input, default-value

I don't remember why i use `this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '':` in the code below, istead of only `this.defaultValue`.

```
$('input:text, textarea').blur(function() {
if ($.trim(this.value) == ''){
this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
}
});
```

**Why not this:**

```
$('input:text, textarea').blur(function() {
if ($.trim(this.value) == ''){
this.value = this.defaultValue;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because if `defaultValue` is not defined, you'll get `'undefined'` instead of `''`

Answer (score 1):

It's a security. In case `this.defaultValue` is `undefined`, it returns an empty string, avoiding `this.value` to receive undefined.

The thing is that this property is only available for `<input>´ and``, pretty much limiting the scope of such a feature. It's pretty common to have selects in a form for instance.

A more straightforward approach would be to use store the default values in a `"data-"` attribute. It's an HTML5 feature but it has a sort-of backward compatibility as they are just html attributes.

```
<select data-defaultValue="1">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

And you can access the attribute with:

```
$('select').attr('data-defaultValue');
// or
$('select').data('defaultValue');
```

More info:

- [HTML5 data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)
- [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, why not use HTML5's placeholder attribute- you don't have to play around with defaultValue. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

It is not supported on IE as far as I know, but works well on others